# C++: Insert an element in a Vector without insert()

Tags: c++, vector, insert, stdvector

I have been trying to solve the above problem for a friend, everytime the last element of the vector gets removed although I feel that its size should increase dynamically after insertion.
Here's the Code:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>   
using namespace std;
void display(vector<int> arr){
    cout<<"Result"<<endl;
    for(auto &p: arr){
        cout<<p<<endl;
    }
}
void indsert(vector<int> arr, int size, int element, int ind){
    for(int i=size+1; i>=ind; i--)
        arr[i] = arr[i-1];
    arr[ind] = element;
    display(arr);
}
int main()
{
    int ind,size,element;
    cout<<"Enter the size of the array"<<endl;
    cin>>size;
    vector<int> arr;
    cout<<"Enter the elements of the array"<<endl;
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
        int temp;
        cin>> temp;
        arr.push_back(temp);
    }
    cout<<"Enter the element to be inserted"<<endl;
    cin>>element;
    cout<<"Enter the index"<<endl;
    cin>>ind;
    indsert(arr, size, element, ind);
    
return 0;
}
```

Comment: "I feel that its size should increase dynamically after insertion" - no, sorry, where did you get this from? Accessing a vector out of bounds is undefined behaviour.

Comment: Stop using `[]` and use `at()`. You will safe yourself a lot of time debugging problems.

Comment: If you are inserting an element then your code should explicitly resize before shuffling elements.   Otherwise your code will write past the end of the vector, which causes undefined behaviour.   Resizing does not happen unless you explicitly make it happen.

Comment: *I feel that its size should increase dynamically after insertion* -- You should read the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at) before wasting a lot of development time assuming how things work.  Nowhere does it say that the vector is resized when using `[ ]`.

Comment: Why not simply use `insert()`?  Every C++ programmer that has a little experience knows exactly what `insert()` does, it is documented, etc.   Who knows what your `indsert()` does, whether it is buggy or not, etc.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes definitely, I was just trying to figure out some concepts of vectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems.

The first is with the function signature:

```
void indsert(vector<int> arr, ...)
```

You pass the vector *by value*. That means a *copy* of the vector is made, and that copy is passed to the function.

You can modify this copy as much as you want, but the original vector will still not change.

You need to pass the vector by *reference*:'

```
void indsert(vector<int>& arr, ...)
//                      ^
// Note ampersand here, making this a reference
```

---

The second problem is much worse: You seem to assume that you can insert into a vector using the `[]` operator. That's not what's happening.

Instead you go *out of bounds* of the vector, which leads to *undefined behavior*.

You need to explicitly resize the vector, either using `insert`, `push_back`/`emplace_back`, or `resize`.

Also remember that since indexes are zero-based, the top-index is the same as the vector size *minus one*. Using the vector size as index will be out of bounds. Using the vector size plus one is even more out of bounds.

Comment: But OP is printing the vector (the copied one) from `indsert` (sic!), not ouside of it.

Comment: Can you show how the indsert was supposed to be written? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Add `emplace_back` to the list of functions.

Comment: @AnirbanSaha `indsert` is just not supposed to be written. You are supposed to use the `insert` member function of the vector.

Comment: @JakobStark Yes I definitely can but I was trying to figure out how can the way I tried be done to get a better understanding of vectors.

Answer (score 0):

Your code exhibits undefined behaviour. You are accessing `arr[size+1]` in a vector `arr` of size `size`. Such a vector has values at positions `0` up to and including `size-1`.

If you want to append a value, use `std::vector::push_back()`. Alternatively you can `std::vector::resize()` the vector beforehand.

---

Also, you don't need to pass the size argument because `std::vector::size()` will tell you the current size of the vector. Furthermore, as has been pointed out to you, pass the vector by reference to avoid copying data for no reason.